# Mongodb - how to get total no.of queries executed in an hour

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

All my Application servers are using single Mongos Router, and they execute tons of queries in some scenarios.
So Mongo I/O is the bottleneck for services performance/scaling.

**I need to identify no.of queries(insert/find/update) executed in a span of time.**
So that i can identify bottlenecks to optimise.

Note: Adding counters in application server is not easy for me, as we have many servers running in distributed clusters.

Comment: u tried profiler? -  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/